# Elasticsearch '[bool] failed to parse field [filter]' exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to solve parsing exception of my search query.
I would like to get some help there :)

The exception reason:
'[1:65] [bool] failed to parse field [filter]'
message:'x_content_parse_exception'

My search:

```
data = (await this.elasticClient.search({
        index: Indexes.Measurements,
        size: 10000,
        body: {
          query: {
            bool: {
              filter: {
                terms: {
                  "MachineId": ["mo3", "mo2"]
                },
                range: {
                  '@timestamp': {
                    gte: `now-${lastMinutes}m`,
                    lte: 'now'
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          },
          sort : [{ "@timestamp" : "desc" }]
      }})).body.hits.hits.map(data => data._source);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `[]` around the `filter` clause, try out this below query

```
data = (await this.elasticClient.search({
        index: Indexes.Measurements,
        size: 10000,
        body: {
          query: {
            bool: {
              filter: [{
                terms: {
                  "MachineId": ["mo3", "mo2"]
                }},{
                range: {
                  '@timestamp': {
                    gte: `now-${lastMinutes}m`,
                    lte: 'now'
                  }
                }}]
              }
            },
          },
          sort : [{ "@timestamp" : "desc" }]
      }})).body.hits.hits.map(data => data._source);
```

In JSON format, it will be like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "MachineId": [
              "mo3",
              "mo2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-${lastMinutes}m",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @RanNissan I have added the query in JSON format also, try to match the brackets from that, as the error clearly shows that the query is not properly formed.

Answer (score 1):

the exception message also appears if the query string is longer than 10000.

V8 ElasticSearchClient's JsonpUtils has a default max length of 10000, cutting longer queries (and adding "..."). So JSON no longer is valid.

We had to set a new max length with "JsonpUtils.maxToStringLength(500000);"
(at your own risk...)